# Conditional View Output?

Tags: 7, views

A view I'm working on has a linked Title field. By default, this field should link to an internal page with the `[nid]`. E.g. http://www.example.com/node/[nid]

However, there is a second link field where, if filled in, the link should be re-written to go to the specified link.

So, if the link field is blank, link to a URL with the `[nid]`. If the link field is filled in, link to the specified URL. I'm unsure of how to have a default behavior and then override it.

How could I accomplish something like this from within Views? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views Conditional module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional), can help you.

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define
>   conditionals (if xxx then yyy) with fields in views. Conditions
>   include:
>
> Equal To Not Equal To Greater Than Less Than Empty Not Empty Views
>   conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the
>   condition.

Example screenshots

1. Added Fields in view

[image]

2. Views Conditional Field configuration

[image]